# converting 0+1 raid array to 0

Tags: raid

I'm currently running raid 0+1; four 500 GB drives in the array..

I'm looking at migrating the array from 0+1 (Stripe+Mirror) to 0 only (stripe).. The goal is to remove the hard drives from the array in order to put them in the newly purchased Drobo, then copy the data from the remaining striped raid to the said Drobo..

Is it sufficient to just remove the drives themselves and change the raid configuration within the nvidia raid config?? Or is there something more that needs to be done?? Does the order matter (i.e. removing drives first or changing the raid configuration??)

Is it possible to migrate the array this way without having any loss of data? I'm wary about burning all that data to DVDs (few hundred GB worth) to back it up..

Any other advice from people that may have done this (or have other insight) would be helpful as well..

Comment: This probably belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: I'd keep the existing array as-is if it was me, you know...

Comment: Buy new drives and put them in the Drobo.  500Gs are cheap, your data isn't :)

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely not possible to migrate the array in this manner without losing all of the data on the disks.  You will need a backup.

You do not need to do anything with the nVidia raid software, simply remove the disks (After backing them up) and put them in the Drobo.  Tell the Drobo you want a massive RAID 0 and off you go.

You seem concerned about loss of data quite a bit, yet you're copying it all to a RAID 0?  In RAID 0 one disk dies and you have **absolutely nothing**.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you can remove the redundant drives from the existing array (identifying which ones are the redundant ones could be fun, though), and create a new degraded RAID-10 on the Drobo, copy the data across, then add the rest of the disks from the old array into the new array to bring it up to spec.  However, if you lose a disk during this procedure or otherwise screw something up, your data is toast.  I'd be buying some new drives for the Drobo, as others have suggested.

Comment: I note that you said you are moving to RAID 0 and this answer suggested using RAID 10. Please listen to him. RAID 10, or stripe of mirrors is the safest way to use a small number of large hard drives, and 500 gig is getting into the risky area where RAID 10 is the preferred solution. So, buy new drives and use RAID 10 from now on.